# iOS build Multiple issues.

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

iOS build of an app has multiple issues some listed below.

1. iOS build of the same app is flaky when navigating through forms. Previous form elements show together with current form elements making app distorted on iPhone/iPad ... iDevices. Android works perfect.
2. SpanLabel distorts on iOS.
3. Some base theme elements look different on iDevices. Should there be an override theme for iDevices?
4. SideMenu shows with a back button on iOS on Forms where SideMenu is not supposed to show.
5. SideMenu shows either a back button or a command with the Main Form title area's text as the first command in SideMenu when the current form is not the Main form

Any suggestions and/resource on the right approach to iOS builds.

Attached is the constants defined in the app

[image: App constants]

Comment: I suggest splitting this up to 5 different questions and providing proper details for each one. Screenshots of simulator vs. device, specific examples rather than wide sweeping examples.

Comment: Thanks Shai. Will split each issue into a different question with screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

3. All OS styles look different between OS's they should look the same as they do on the simulator. I would suggest avoiding the theme override option unless you really need it as it has hidden complexities.
4. Try defining the theme constant `hideBackCommandBool=true`